# Protobuf to mxArray Routine Segfaults

Tags: c++, matlab, protocol-buffers

I'm having some difficulty with a mex function that I'm writing to convert Protobuf messages in C++ to mxArrays that are then returned as Matlab structures.  It seems to run ok - I was able to confirm that it runs all the way through a sample message - but it segfaults as the mex function is returning.  That's made it a bit difficult for me to debug, and I suspect that I'm doing something pretty dumb (well, probably multiple things pretty dumb).  I've been staring at this for hours and haven't made much progress.  Can anyone take a look at this code and see what might be going on?  Thanks so much for any help:

```
mxArray* processPbMessage(const ::google::protobuf::Message* inMsg)
{
// Set up a namespace for convenience for protobuf stuff
namespace pb = ::google::protobuf;

// Extract a descriptor and reflection for the incoming message
const pb::Descriptor* descriptor = inMsg->GetDescriptor();
const pb::Reflection* reflection = inMsg->GetReflection();

// Extract the fields from the message
vector<const pb::FieldDescriptor*> fields;
reflection->ListFields(*inMsg, &fields);
const int numFields = fields.size();
const char **field_names = new const char*[numFields];
const pb::FieldDescriptor* iField;

// Put the fields into a C style array
for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fields.size(); fieldIndex++)
{
    iField = fields[fieldIndex];
    field_names[fieldIndex] = iField->name().c_str();
}

// Create a Matlab structure
mwSize dims[2] = {1, 1};
mxArray *mexMsg = mxCreateStructArray(2, dims, fields.size(), field_names);
delete[] field_names;

// Initialize varaibles to hold the various value types that we might find

// Values that we extract from the protobuf messages
int intValue;
double valueDouble;
float valueFloat;
string valueString;
const pb::EnumValueDescriptor* valueEnum;
bool valueBool;

int count;

// Submessage varaibles
mxArray* mxSubMessage;
mxArray* nextField;
const pb::Descriptor* subDescriptor;
const pb::Reflection* subReflection;
vector<const pb::FieldDescriptor*> subFields;
int subNumFields;
const pb::FieldDescriptor* subIField;
int subFieldIndex;
mxArray *subMexMsg;

// Iterate through each field in the incoming message (note: this will only handle single messages)
for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
{

    // Extract the descriptor for this field
    const pb::FieldDescriptor* thisField = fields[i];
    const char **subFieldNames;

    // Determine if this field is repeated and, if so, how many fields there are
    count = 0;
    if (thisField->is_repeated())
    {
        count = reflection->FieldSize(*inMsg, thisField);
    }
    else if (reflection->HasField(*inMsg, thisField))
    {
        count = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Field Issue!");
    }

    // Determine the name of the field
    string fieldName = thisField->name();

    // Recurse, if necessary
    if (thisField->cpp_type() == pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_MESSAGE)
    {

        // If it's greater than 0, we have a repeated field.  Otherwise, it's singular
        if (count > 0)
        {

            // Create a struct array for this field
            const pb::Message& firstMessage = (reflection->GetRepeatedMessage(*inMsg, thisField, 0));
            subDescriptor = firstMessage.GetDescriptor();
            subReflection = firstMessage.GetReflection();
            subReflection->ListFields(firstMessage, &subFields);
            subNumFields = subFields.size();
            subFieldNames = new const char*[subNumFields];
            for (subFieldIndex = 0; subFieldIndex < subFields.size(); subFieldIndex++)
            {
                subIField = subFields[subFieldIndex];
                subFieldNames[subFieldIndex] = subIField->name().c_str();
            }
            mwSize dims[2] = {count, 1};
            subMexMsg = mxCreateStructArray(2, dims, subFields.size(), subFieldNames);

            // Iterate through each repeated message
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
            {
                // Call this method on the sub message
                const pb::Message& recurseMessage = reflection->GetRepeatedMessage(*inMsg, thisField, j);
                mxSubMessage = processPbMessage(&recurseMessage);

                // Itereate through and set each field
                for (int subFieldIndex = 0; subFieldIndex < subFields.size(); subFieldIndex++)
                {
                    nextField = mxGetField(mxSubMessage, 0, subFieldNames[subFieldIndex]);
                    mxSetField(subMexMsg, j, subFieldNames[subFieldIndex], nextField);
                }

                delete[] subFieldNames;

                mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), subMexMsg);

            }
            else
            {
                // Call this method on the sub-message
                const pb::Message& subMessage = reflection->GetMessage(*inMsg, thisField);
                mxSubMessage = processPbMessage(&subMessage);
                mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxSubMessage);
            }

        }
        else if (count <= 0)
        {
            // In this case, the field is not repeated and is not a message.  Add it to the Matlab structure
            switch(thisField->cpp_type())
            {
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT32 :
                    intValue = reflection->GetInt32(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateDoubleScalar((double) intValue));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT64 :
                    intValue = reflection->GetInt64(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateDoubleScalar((double) intValue));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT32 :
                    intValue = reflection->GetUInt32(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateDoubleScalar((double) intValue));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT64 :
                    intValue = reflection->GetUInt64(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateDoubleScalar((double) intValue));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_DOUBLE :
                    valueDouble = reflection->GetDouble(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateDoubleScalar(valueDouble));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_FLOAT :
                    valueFloat = reflection->GetFloat(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateDoubleScalar((double) valueFloat));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_BOOL :
                    valueBool = reflection->GetBool(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateLogicalScalar(valueBool));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_ENUM :
                    valueEnum = reflection->GetEnum(*inMsg, thisField);
                    valueString = valueEnum->name();
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateString(valueString.c_str()));
                    break;
                case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_STRING :
                    valueString = reflection->GetString(*inMsg, thisField);
                    mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), mxCreateString(valueString.c_str()));
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{

            // In this case, the field is repeated. Go through each repetition
            mxArray *value;
            mwSize dims2[2] = {1, count};
            double *doubleArray;
            mxLogical *boolArray;
            mxChar* charArray;

            // Initialize matrices to hold the repeated data
            switch(thisField->cpp_type())
            {
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT32 :
                        value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, count, mxREAL);
                        doubleArray = mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT64 :
                        value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, count, mxREAL);
                        doubleArray = mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT32 :
                        value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, count, mxREAL);
                        doubleArray = mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT64 :
                        value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, count, mxREAL);
                        doubleArray = mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_DOUBLE :
                        value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, count, mxREAL);
                        doubleArray = mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_FLOAT :
                        value = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, count, mxREAL);
                        doubleArray = mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_BOOL :
                        value = mxCreateLogicalMatrix(1, count);
                        boolArray = (mxLogical *) mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_STRING :
                        value = mxCreateCharArray(1, dims2);
                        charArray = (mxChar *) mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_ENUM :
                        value = mxCreateCharArray(1, dims2);
                        charArray = (mxChar *) mxGetPr(value);
                        break;
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < count; ++k)
            {
                switch(thisField->cpp_type())
                {
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT32 :
                        intValue = reflection->GetRepeatedInt32(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        doubleArray[k] = (double) intValue;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_INT64 :
                        intValue = reflection->GetRepeatedInt64(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        doubleArray[k] = (double) intValue;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT32 :
                        intValue = reflection->GetRepeatedUInt32(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        doubleArray[k] = (double) intValue;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT64 :
                        intValue = reflection->GetRepeatedUInt64(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        doubleArray[k] = (double) intValue;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_DOUBLE :
                        valueDouble = reflection->GetRepeatedDouble(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        doubleArray[k] = valueDouble;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_FLOAT :
                        valueFloat = reflection->GetRepeatedFloat(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        doubleArray[k] = (double) valueFloat;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_BOOL :
                        valueBool = reflection->GetRepeatedBool(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        boolArray[k] = valueBool;
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_STRING :
                        valueString = reflection->GetRepeatedString(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        charArray[k] = (mxChar) valueString.c_str();
                        break;
                    case pb::FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_ENUM :
                        valueEnum = reflection->GetRepeatedEnum(*inMsg, thisField, k);
                        valueString = valueEnum->name();
                        charArray[k] = (mxChar) valueString.c_str();
                        break;
                }
            }

            mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), value);


        }
    }
}

return mexMsg;
```

}

---

Ok, the error could be coming from this section:

```
            // Iterate through each repeated message
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
            {
                // Call this method on the sub message
                const pb::Message& recurseMessage = reflection->GetRepeatedMessage(*inMsg, thisField, j);
                mxSubMessage = processPbMessage(&recurseMessage);

                // Itereate through and set each field
                for (int subFieldIndex = 0; subFieldIndex < subFields.size(); subFieldIndex++)
                {
                    nextField = mxGetField(mxSubMessage, 0, subFieldNames[subFieldIndex]);
                    mxSetField(subMexMsg, j, subFieldNames[subFieldIndex], nextField);
                }

                delete[] subFieldNames;

                mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, fieldName.c_str(), subMexMsg);

            }
```

When I comment out the first mxSetField line, the segfault goes away.  But I can't see anything wrong with the way I'm doing this.  Am I setting fields of structs of structs incorrectly?

---

Ok, I tried running a very simple example and ran into another issue that I think is very closely related (although the stack trace after the segfault is different). I created a standalone C++ file with this code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "mex.h"

    void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray
*prhs[])
    {

        mxSize dims[2] = {1, 1};
        const char* fields1[] = {"field1", "field2"};
        const char* fields2[] = {"field3"};
        mxArray *mexMsg  = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 2, fields1);
        mxArray *subMexMsg = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 2, 1, fields2);
        int intValue = 32;
        mxArray* inputMxArray = mxCreateDoubleScalar((double) intValue);
        mxSetField(subMexMsg, 0, "field3", inputMxArray);
        mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, "field1", subMexMsg);
        mxSetField(mexMsg, 0, "field2", inputMxArray);

        plhs[0] = mexMsg;
    }
```

My goal was to create a structure of structures. The result (let’s call it res) should have looked like this res field1 subMessage field3 32 field2 32

I compiled it with Matlab using mex and ran it. Everything looked fine and as expected. Then I executed ‘clear all’ and it failed with a segfault. I hope that this should be easily repeatable on another machine. I expect that the error came about when trying to clear the mxArrays that were created in the mex function. Anyone know why this error is occurring? Thank you for any help.

Comment: You've provided a *lot* of code, but not given precise details of where the problem is. Can you reduce the code to a short but complete example, and provide details of which statement is segfaulting?

Comment: Well, that's kind of the difficulty.  It segfaults when the mex file is exiting.  That's why I'm not really sure how to approach debugging.  I couldn't get much from it, but I could provide the stack trace, if that may be helpful to someone else.  I will also try to start taking more pieces out and seeing what makes the segfault go away, rather than trying to fix it wholesale.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is get this repo->https://github.com/kyamagu/mexplus and use it to create the correct data types. The second thing you should do, is take a look at this FileExchange entry for wrapping C++ classes->http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38964-example-matlab-class-wrapper-for-a-c++-class

The message object that you're creating is not the same message object that you access the next time you call your mex file.

Indecently, I'm working on something very similar to bring protobuf messages into MATLAB. If I get mine working and posted, I'll post a follow-up here.